# Automatically attach a custom firewall rule to GKE created loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

#### Question

Is it possible to attach a custom firewall rule to a GKE created load balancer?

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#service-fws) are the default firewall rules created.

I have done something similar in AWS in the past, but I am currently having trouble finding a similar annotation (or other process) to automatically add a cloud firewall rule to a load balancer that is created by GKE.

#### Example in AWS

Here is an example of what I've done in AWS in the past for context:

1. Pre-create a Security Group in the AWS console
2. Create a service of `type: Loadbalancer` in a kubernetes cluster deployed in AWS with the following annotation: `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: "sg-53fae93f"`

What this will do is automatically add the security groups `sg-53fae93f` to the load balancer created by kubernetes.

Thank you in advance!